# Check if user is in the defined area

Tags: ios, geolocation, location, area

In my app I want to check if my position is within defined area. I know the area coordinates and I want to check it when app is launched. How can I do it? As far as I know, geofencing can help me, but this technique always scans user's location. And I need only a manual check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've got the users coordinates from a manual check with `CLLocationManager` then store them as a `CLLocation` object, then have another `CLLocation` object that contains the centre point of the region you want to check. You can then use `[someUserLocationObject distanceFromLocation:centralPointOfArea]` which will give you the distance the user is (in metres) from the central point, and you can make a determination from there.